# how to get the region name?

Tags: silverlight, prism

using Silverlight & Prism.
i create a new scoped region inside a TabControl like so:

```
IRegionManager regionManager = tabControl.Add(viewRegions, UNIQUEID, true);
```

then from the TabControl SelectionChanged event i want to get the name of that region.
so i go:

```
TabItem item = e.AddedItems[0] as TabItem;
FrameworkElement view = item.Content as FrameworkElement;
IRegionManager xxx = RegionManager.GetRegionManager(view);
```

so now i have the scoped region manager at hand = xxx!

but how do i get its name? (the "UNIQUEID" param i have assigned to it ).

HOW?

Comment: Your comment below suggests that the question that I was trying to answer is not the question that you were asking.  Can you maybe re-phrase this somehow so that I can understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: look at my code above...
when adding a scoped region it is given a name. in my example above the name is the "UNIQUEID" param.
then later i want to retrieve that name, from within an other class.
i get to the scoped region manager ("xxx" in my example).
how do i get its name??

Comment: You'll do just what I said.  You'll have to go through your IRegionManager's list of regions: xxx.Regions

Comment: doing so will give me the region INSIDE "xxx". i m looking for what is "xxx" name.

Comment: You are wanting the identifier assigned to that view, not the name of the region itself.  Is there a reason you want this?  There is a good chance you will have to track this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the RegionManager, and the View, then you can get the region Name (but I don't know why you'd ever want to).  If you loop through the regionmanger like this you can get what you want.  You'll have to keep a reference around to the scoped RegionManager, but there's no way around that.  (There is some extra code demonstrating other things that someone might want to do too)

```
    private void UnloadRegion()
    {
        foreach (IRegion region in xxx.Regions)
        {
            for (int ix = region.ActiveViews.Count() - 1; ix >= 0; ix--)
            {
               if (WhateverYourCurrentViewIs == region.ActiveViews.Last())
               {
                    string RegionName = region.Name;
                    //there is the name
               {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry but this does not work for me.
when i add a scoped region inside some other region (a TabControl in my case) the newly added scoped region is not inside  _RegionManager.Regions.

Comment: I know that.  I'm saying that you'll have to go through the scoped region just the same as you would the _RegionManager

Comment: i don't get what u mean. how do i know the scoped region name?